# React MUI Select with react-hook-form doesn't work with Cypress

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, cypress, react-hook-form

In my react application I have a form with a dropdown select. Depending on the selected Option different inputs are rendered.

```
    const [templateType, setTemplateType] = useState("");
    const {
     register,
     formState: { errors },
     setValue,
    } = useFormContext();
    ...
    <FormControl>
      <InputLabel>Template Typ</InputLabel>
      <Select id="SelectTemplateType"
        className="custom-input"
        {...register("templateType", { required: true })}
        label="Template Typ"
        value={templateType}
        onChange={(e) => setTemplateType(e.target.value)}
        error={errors.templateType}
      >
        {TEMPLATE_TYPES.map((option) => (
          <MenuItem value={option.value}>{option.label}</MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Select>
      {errors.templateType && (
        <FormHelperText sx={{ color: "#d32f2f" }}>
          Eintrag darf nicht leer sein!
        </FormHelperText>
      )}
    </FormControl>
    <TemplateFormSwitch templateType={templateType} />
```

The TemplateFormSwitch returns different form-components depending on the selected templateType.
I'm using react-hook-form with FormProvider and useFormContext because my form is split up over multiple components/files.

I tried to write a Cypress-Test, by first clicking the select and then clicking on the desired option:

```
    cy.get('#SelectTemplateType').click({ force: true })
    cy.get('[data-value="Text"]').click({ force: true });
    //Entering Test values to TextFields
    cy.get('#mui-1').type("Test");
    cy.get('#mui-2').type("HelloWorld");
```

Then when I try to submit my form all textfields get validated correctly. But somehow the select with the templateType doesn't validate and the submit action gets blocked.
[image: Form Validation Error]
Weirdly when I click manually in the application everything works fine and the templateType select gets validated correctly.

What do I need to do/change in order to test the MUI select correctly and trigger the react-hook-form validation accordingly, like I would if I test manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the javascript code use by commands is not enough to trigger validation checks.

The user will focus and blur each field, so you can also do that

```js
it("form test", () => {
  cy.visit("http://localhost:3000");

  cy.get('[href="/form"] > .MuiListItem-root > .MuiListItemButton-root')
    .click();

  cy.get("#SelectGenderType").click();
  cy.get('[data-value="m"]').click()
  cy.get("#SelectGenderType").focus().blur()

  cy.get("form > :nth-child(1) > :nth-child(2)").type("Max");
  cy.get("form > :nth-child(1) > :nth-child(3)").type("Mustermann");

  cy.get(".MuiButton-root")
    .click();

  cy.contains('p', 'Field cannot be empty!').should('not.exist')    // ✅ passes
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I cloned your Repo and ran the test, but for me there was no error that was produced. I ran the exact script.

```js
describe('my test spec', () => {
  it('form test', () => {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:3000')

    cy.get(
      '[href="/form"] > .MuiListItem-root > .MuiListItemButton-root'
    ).click()

    cy.get('#SelectGenderType').click()

    cy.get('[data-value="m"]').click()

    cy.get('form > :nth-child(1) > :nth-child(2)').type('Max')
    cy.get('form > :nth-child(1) > :nth-child(3)').type('Mustermann')

    cy.get('.MuiButton-root').click()
  })
})
```

Screenshot of the test runner:

[image: Test Runner Screenshot]

Comment: Strangely when I first run the test, it passes no problem. But when I change the test or just save the file, so it gets reloaded by cypress I get the described error

Comment: I tried re-running the tests manually and also by making changes to the test file. Also ran the tests in Chrome, Firefox, Edge and Electron browsers and for every scenario, I was getting a pass.